# detect closest repository

Tags: r

Is there a way to detect the closest R repository?  This doesn't have to be perfect just reasonably close.

I'll discuss the big picture as there may be a better way of going about what I'm doing.  I'm writing a package that uses `available.packages()`.

This throws up an error when I check the package saying:

```
Error in contrib.url(getOption("repos"), type):
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror.
Calls: p_cran -> available.packages -> contrib.url
Execution is halted
```

My thoughts are to set the mirror temporary using something like:

```
x <- getOption("repos")
#SOME HOW TEST IF x IS NOT SET BUT NOT SURE HOW
if (is.not.set(x)){
    y <- get.local.mirror.function()
    options(repos=structure(c(CRAN=y)))
    on.exit(options(repos=structure(c(CRAN=x))))
}
```

So I guess I have two problems to overcome if this route is reasonable:

1. Determine if the `repos` has been set
2. Find closest or some default to put in as the repos

Thank you in advance for help figuring this out.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-July/206430.html

Comment: @BenBolker I found that one.  it's slow as it checks all the repositories for speed.  I was hoping there's a way to check the system for location somehow and find a repos in close proximity.  What if I just used the same repos for everyone (if they don't already have it set)?  Or I could annotate the examples in the manaul with `#` as it'll still work but doesn't pass the check so that's a way around I've seen people do to pass checks.

Comment: Also possibly useful: http://onertipaday.blogspot.com/2009/08/locate-position-of-cran-mirror-sites-on.html (and also leading back ultimately to @Spacedman ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part of this problem isn't getting the locations of the R repositories - it should be pretty easy to keep a constant that records where the major ones are. The tricky part is *finding the user's own location*.

What I'd suggest is to examine timezone settings. You can read `Sys.timezone()` directly and apply to a lookup table, but that's a string and it might be a pain. I'd instead try to find the UTC offset, by, e.g.

```
tmp = as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
offset =  as.numeric(as.POSIXct(format(tmp))) 
         - as.numeric(as.POSIXct(format(tmp, tz = "UTC")))
```

Then you can look up the offset against some kind of table, and match each band to some repository. Be sure to consider the case where a repository is down, or something...

To be fair, you can probably get pretty reasonable results by just selecting a random repository. (Maybe excluding some of the ones out in the middle of nowhere...)

Determining whether repos have been set is a simple matter of looking up `options("repos")` or `getOption("repos")`. From `?options`:

```
‘repos’: URLs of the repositories for use by ‘update.packages’.
      Defaults to ‘c(CRAN="@CRAN@")’, a value that causes some
      utilities to prompt for a CRAN mirror.
```

So `(getOption("repos")[1] == "@CRAN@")` should work.

Comment: or `getOption("repos")`, marginally more convenient

Comment: I like the time zone idea.  Nice approach.  The testing repos isn't that simple I think.  The function was to check if it's been set and I can't seem to do a logical test as the default for me seems to be: `getOption("repos")`:  `                               CRAN                            CRANextra 
                            "@CRAN@" "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin" 
`

Comment: for me `getOption("repos")=="@CRAN@"` is `TRUE` if I run with `--vanilla`

Comment: Okay, I've changed it to explain about this.